# Python numpy upgrade failing test for percentile method

Tags: python, numpy

When I have updated the `numpy` version from `1.11.3` to `1.16.5`, my tests are failing because of of fraction difference between the values calculated by the `percentile` method.

**numpy = 1.11.3**

```
import numpy as np
print (np.percentile([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [15.0, 85.0])[1])
> 0.54999999999999982
```

**numpy = 1.16.5**

```
import numpy as np
print (np.percentile([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [15.0, 85.0])[1])
> 0.5499999999999998
```

I am looking for an answer that what has changed that is causing the failure, I wanted to understand the upgrade so that I do not get unexpected results once released to prod.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your test is fine, you are just printing two different precisions

```py
import numpy as np
print (np.percentile([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [15.0, 85.0])[1])
> 0.54999999999999982 # has 17 decimal places
```

```py
import numpy as np
print (np.percentile([1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [15.0, 85.0])[1])
> 0.5499999999999998 # has only 16
```

the actual value is indeed `0.54999999999999982236`. So your test is fine.

To make sure your numeric tests with `numpy` work as expected , you can setup the precision of printed values with `np.set_printoptions(precision=20)` .